# Get Range with If Condition

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using app script, I'd like to create a macro that fetches a cell array from a different sheet. None of the the cells in the array actually have values though, but they do have data validation applied with specific lists for each cell.

Based on the user input, I have an IF formula in the cells above that populate a 1 or 0 if that cell needs to be included in the range to be fetched.

ROW 1 = IF formula that populates in line with user input
ROW 2 = target range
ROW 3 = formulas that populates values for each data validation list (not relevant)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIE9r.png)

Comment: If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.googlec.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If  you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details.